# CodecConfigurationException Can't find a codec for DateTime In MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm using Mongodb with Spring Boot (1.4.4.RELEASE), I store an object in a MongoDB database and am getting a CodecConfigurationException  When i try to get Object with AggregationOperation.

My MongoDbConfig is

```
@Configuration
public class MongoDbConfig {

    @Value("${mongodb_host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${mongodb_port}")
    private String port;

    @Value("${mongodb_name}")
    private String dataBase;

    @Value("${mongodb_username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${mongodb_password}")
    private String password;    

    public @Bean MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017), new ArrayList<MongoCredential>() {
            {
               add(MongoCredential.createCredential(userName, dataBase,password.toCharArray()));
            }
        });
    }

    public @Bean MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception { 
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient(), dataBase);
    }
    @Bean
     public  MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
        return mongoTemplate;
    }  
}
```

My Document is

```
@Document(collection = "FuelBook")
public class FuelBook implements Serializable {
    private String orgId;
    private String branchId;
    private String vehicleId;
    private String driverName;
    private DateTime date;  
    private boolean isActive = true;
    private Double kmsReading;
    private float costOfFuel;
    private String typeOfFuel;
//getter and setter
}
```

I am creating Document using below code

```
public String addFuelBookDetails(AddFuelBookDetailsDTO request,
            String orgId, String branchId, String vehicleId) {
        try{            
            if(!mongoTemplate.collectionExists(FuelBook.class)){
                mongoTemplate.createCollection(FuelBook.class);
            }
            FuelBook fuelBook = new FuelBook();
            fuelBook.setOrgId(orgId);
            fuelBook.setBranchId(branchId);
            fuelBook.setVehicleId(vehicleId);
            fuelBook.setDriverName(request.getDriverName());
            fuelBook.setDate(TimeConversionHelper.getJodaDate(request.getDate(), 
            "yyyy-MM-dd"));
            fuelBook.setCostOfFuel(Float.parseFloat((request.getCostOfFuel())));
            fuelBook.setKmsReading(Double.parseDouble(request.getKmsReading()));
            fuelBook.setTypeOfFuel(request.getTypeOfFuel());
            mongoTemplate.insert(fuelBook, "FuelBook");
            return StringConstants.SUCCESS;

        } catch(Exception e) {
       return null;
        }   
    }
```

And this code to create String To DateTime

```
public static DateTime getJodaDate(String dateString, String format) {
        DateTime dateTime = null;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            Date date = (Date) sdf.parse(dateString);
            long timeInMillis = date.getTime();
            dateTime = new DateTime(timeInMillis);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {           
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dateTime;
    }
```

Using below code try to get All FuelBooks

```
    AggregationOperation org = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("orgId").is(orgId));
    AggregationOperation branch = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("branchId").is(branchId));
    AggregationOperation vehicle = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("vehicleId").is(vehicleId));            
    DateTime jodaStartTime = TimeConversionHelper.getJodaDate(request.getStartTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
    DateTime jodaEndTime = TimeConversionHelper.getJodaDate(request.getEndTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
    AggregationOperation startTime = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("date").gte(jodaStartTime));
    AggregationOperation endTime = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("date").lte(jodaEndTime));
    AggregationOperation  offsetAggregation=Aggregation.skip(offset);
    AggregationOperation limitAggregation=Aggregation.limit(limit);
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(org, branch, vehicle, startTime, endTime,offsetAggregation,limitAggregation);          
    AggregationResults<FuelBook> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "FuelBook" ,FuelBook.class);         
    if(result!=null && result.getMappedResults()!=null && !result.getMappedResults().isEmpty()) {
    List<FuelBook>  fuelLists = result.getMappedResults();
```

However, I'm running into this error message:

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.joda.time.DateTime.
        at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46)
        at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63)
        at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:37)
        at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.writeValue(DBObjectCodec.java:210)
        at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encodeMap(DBObjectCodec.java:220)
        at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.writeValue(DBObjectCodec.java:196)
        at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encodeMap(DBObjectCodec.java:220)
        at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.writeValue(DBObjectCodec.java:196)
        at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encodeMap(DBObjectCodec.java:220)
        at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.writeValue(DBObjectCodec.java:196)
        at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encodeIterable(DBObjectCodec.java:269)
        at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.writeValue(DBObjectCodec.java:198)
        at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encode(DBObjectCodec.java:128)
        at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encode(DBObjectCodec.java:61)
        at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
        at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
        at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.addDocument(RequestMessage.java:253)
        at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.addDocument(RequestMessage.java:205)
        at com.mongodb.connection.CommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(CommandMessage.java:75)
        at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.encodeWithMetadata(RequestMessage.java:160)
        at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.sendMessage(CommandProtocol.java:184)
        at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.execute(CommandProtocol.java:108)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:159)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:286)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:173)
        at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:215)
        at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:186)
        at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:178)
        at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:91)
        at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:84)
        at com.mongodb.operation.CommandReadOperation.execute(CommandReadOperation.java:55)
        at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:773)
        at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:760)
        at com.mongodb.DB.executeCommand(DB.java:653)
        at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:423)
        at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:439)
        at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:394)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$3.doInDB(MongoTemplate.java:390)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$3.doInDB(MongoTemplate.java:388)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:446)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeCommand(MongoTemplate.java:388)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1556)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1491)
        at com.icarat.eshiksha.mongodb.dao.impl.FuelBookDAOImpl.getFuelBookDetails(FuelBookDAOImpl.java:153)
        at com.icarat.eshiksha.rest.controller.FuelBookController.getFuelBookDetails(FuelBookController.java:132)
```

Can anyone can provide some insight on why this is happening? Thank you

Comment: How does your spring config look like ? `JodaTimeConverters` should be automatically registered with Mongo.

Comment: @veeram i updated my question. JodaTimeConverts is class with static methods sir

Comment: Your config looks good. Spring auto registers it when it finds the joda jar in classpath. . Check the `CustomConversions` constructor. You can try debugging that class.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23131817/8062907) link

I change my mongoClient in MongoDbConfig like

```
 public @Bean MongoClient mongoClient() {
     BSON.addEncodingHook(DateTime.class, new JodaTimeTransformer());
     BSON.addDecodingHook(Date.class, new JodaTimeTransformer());
     return new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017), new ArrayList<MongoCredential>() {
                  {
           add(MongoCredential.createCredential(userName, dataBase,password.toCharArray()));
                   }
                          });
  }
```

And i just add JodaTimeTransformer class into my project classPath